# Docker no space left on device on Mac M1

Tags: ios, docker

I want to run container and receive error:

```
docker run -ti --rm grafana/promtail:2.5.0 -config.file=/etc/promtail/config.yml
docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0cad6a6645e2445a9985d5c9e9c6909fa74ee1a30425b407ddfac13684bd9d31-init: no space left on device.
```

At first, I thought I have a lot of volumes and images cached. So I clean docker with:

```
docker prune
docker builder prune
```

But in a while, the same error occur. When I check my Docker Desktop configuration, I can see I am using all available disk size for images:

```
Disk image size:
59.6 GB (59.5 GB used)
```

I have 13 images on my system and together its less than **5GB**:

```
REPOSITORY                           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
logstashloki                         latest    157966144f3b   3 days ago     761MB
minio/minio                          <none>    717586e37f7f   4 days ago     232MB
grafana/grafana                      <none>    31a8875955e5   9 days ago     277MB
docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat     8.3.2     e7b210caf528   3 weeks ago    295MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver            v1.24.0   b62a103951f4   2 months ago   126MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler            v1.24.0   b81513b3bfb4   2 months ago   50MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager   v1.24.0   59fad34d4fe0   2 months ago   116MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy                v1.24.0   66e1443684b0   2 months ago   106MB
k8s.gcr.io/etcd                      3.5.3-0   a9a710bb96df   3 months ago   178MB
grafana/promtail                     2.5.0     aa21fd577ae2   3 months ago   177MB
grafana/loki                         2.5.0     369cbd28ef9b   3 months ago   60MB
k8s.gcr.io/pause                     3.7       e5a475a03805   4 months ago   514kB
k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns           v1.8.6    edaa71f2aee8   9 months ago   46.8MB
```

From output of `docker system df` there is no suspicious size of container, images or volumes:

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          13        13        2.35GB    69.57MB (2%)
Containers      21        21        35.15kB   0B (0%)
Local Volumes   2         0         2.186MB   2.186MB (100%)
Build Cache     20        0         0B        0B
```

I am new to MacOS and cannot determine what take all my space and how to clean all that space and where are all that data stored on system?

Comment: I see that you have 21 active (running) container. You should try to stop `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` and remove `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` them to free up space. Note you can see the size used by containers `docker ps --all --size`.

Comment: Try a 'docker system prune'.  I did that on my MacBook (Intel) and removed far more Gb's than the total of 'docker images' showed.